# How can I center my text using Divs

Tags: html, css

I had this code and it worked good. The footer information was at the bottom of my screen in the middle:

```
div#footercenter p { font-size: 0.9em; }

<div id="footercenter">
  <p>&#169; XXXX </p>
</div>
```

I wanted to change it to this:

```
div#footercenter {}
div#footer-message { font-size: 0.9em; color: #EEEEEE;  display: inline;}
div#footer-copyright { font-size: 0.9em; color: #EEEEEE; display: inline; }

<div id="footercenter">
  <div id="footer-copyright">xxx</div>|
  <div id="footer-message">yyy</div>
</div>
```

Now my text is to the left and not in the center. Does anyone have any idea how I can make it go back to the center?

Dave

Comment: too many people are too fast before i type the answer.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/DHA9A/

You just need to add `text-align` to `center`

```
div#footercenter {text-align: center}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this:

```
#footercenter {
    text-align:center;
}
```

But you may need to do this as well if you have other styles interfering:

```
#footercenter div {
    float:none;
    display:inline; /* or inline-block */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is a block element that should be used for defining collections of elements rather than explicitly for text content. There's nothing wrong with your markup but you have set your divs to then have a display:inline which means they only occupy the width of their content. The divs will also bunch up to the left by default.

The better approach would have been to contain the text within 2 span elements and then simply set the text-align property of the parent div to center.

See the following;

```
div#footercenter { font-size: 0.9em; color: #EEEEEE; text-align:center; }

<div id="footercenter">
  <span>xxx</span>|
  <span>yyy</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div#footercenter {
  text-align:center;
}

<div id="footercenter">
  <span id="footer-copyright">xxx</span>|
  <span id="footer-message">yyy</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your footercenter class as

```
div#footercenter {text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width for the div you wanna apply the text-align property to and then assign `text-align : center.`